# How to pass minutes to datetime.time

Tags: python

Is it possible to do the following in some way?

```
datetime.time(minute=144)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: minute must be in 0..59
```

Comment: So you are expecting minutes to hours kind of conversion ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `datetime.timedelta` may be more appropriate.

Comment: `datetime.time()` is the wrong type for a *duration*. Use a `timedelta()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way if you're going to convert it:

```
hour = minutes / 60
minute = minutes % 60
```